# Linux platform tag for python module built with pybind11

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pypi, pybind11

I am using pybind11 and build the python module with setuptools and cmake as described in [pybind/cmake_example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py):

```
setup(
    name='libraryname',
    ...
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension('libraryname')],
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
)
```

Locally, using `python setup.py sdist build` everything is fine and I can use and/or install the package from the generated files.

**I now want to upload the package to PyPI**.
From a different python package I know how to generate a general linux library (see also [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/)) by manipulating the platform tag of a wheel:

```
class bdist_wheel(bdist_wheel_):
    def finalize_options(self):
        from sys import platform as _platform
        platform_name = get_platform()
        if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
            # Linux
            platform_name = 'manylinux1_x86_64'

        bdist_wheel_.finalize_options(self)
        self.universal = True
        self.plat_name_supplied = True
        self.plat_name = platform_name

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass = {'bdist_wheel': bdist_wheel},
)
```

### The Question:

How to generate the appropriate platform tag when no `bdist_wheel` is built?
Should this be somehow built as wheel instead of as an extension (possibly related to [this issue on GH](https://github.com/pybind/python_example/issues/20))?

Also, how does pybind11 decide the suffix of the generated libraries (on my linux it is not just `.so` but `.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`)?

### Follow-up:

- The main problem is that I cannot update the current Ubuntu-built package to PyPI: `ValueError: Unknown distribution format: 'libraryname-0.8.0.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'`
- If the platform tag cannot or should not be changed: what is best practice for uploading a pybind11 module to PyPI across platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My bad!**

It turns out the confusion was due to a build error I had when I initially tried running `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`.
Manually building with `python setup.py build` was not the right approach for publishing the package.

*Note*: the name of the .so file needed to be set without the `-0.8.0` version identifier in order for python do be able to do the import from the wheel.

To Summarize:
**Building and publishing binary wheels works exactly the same with pybind11 as with e.g. cpython** and it should work just fine to follow the [pybind/cmake_example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example).